# Why can't I write to a file?

Tags: file, haskell, io

I am trying to create a `csv` file for testing purposes and when I try to write it, it continues to fluctuate either at `0kb` or `1kb` and only 1 record is written. It continues to fluctuate like this for a while until I get

> openfile: permission denied

```
module Generator where 

    path="d:\\data.csv"
    cnt=1000000
    main::IO()
    main=do
        let payload=makeString
        writeToFile path cnt payload


    makeString::String
    makeString="0741142339,\r\n"

    writeToFile::String->Int->String->IO()
    writeToFile _ 0 _ =return ()
    writeToFile path cnt payload=writeFile path payload >> writeToFile path (cnt-1)  payload
```

If I try to write to a location on `C://` I get not allowed permission.

Comment: `writeToFile path cnt payload = replicateM_ cnt (writeFile path payload)`; no explicit recursion needed. The same logic holds if you replace `writeFile` with `appendFile`, as recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each call to `writeFile` overwrites the existing file with the next record.

What you want to do is *either*

- Open the file (`openFile`), write each line to the file handle (`hPutStrLn`), close the file at the end (`hClose`).
- Generate a giant string representing the entire file contents, and `writeFile` that at the end.

Comment: check also `appendFile`